# How can I use pre-trained weights from an existing CNN model for transfer learning in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working on a 2D RGB pixel-based image classification problem via convolution neural networks (CNN) in Keras. My full CNN model can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8871bec87bcdd5375326e9511cec0718).

I do the following to train/fit the CNN model:

```
model =  my_CNN_unet()

model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('testweights_{epoch:02d}.hdf5')
model.fit(x_trn, y_trn, batch_size=50, epochs=3, verbose=1, shuffle=True,
callbacks=[model_checkpoint], validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

How can I change my code, so that I use pre-trained weights (i.e., transfer learning) from well-known CNN architectures such as `VGG` and `Inception`

Comment: "Is it simple as using ..." -- did you try it? What happened?

Comment: https://keras.io/applications/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have mentioned in the comments, `keras.applications` provides a way for you to access pretrained models. As an example:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Model

model_base = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(*IMG_SIZE, 3), weights='imagenet')
output = model_base.output
# Add any other layers you want to `output` here...
output = Dense(len(categories), activation='softmax')(output)
model = Model(model_base.input, output)
for layer in model_base.layers:
   layer.trainable = False
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
return model
```

You can train this model in the same way you trained your previous CNN. Keras applications provides access to many models such as Inception, VGG16, VGG19, ResNet, and more-- you can access them all in a similar way. I wrote a blog post walking through how to use transfer learning in Keras to build an image classifier here: http://innolitics.com/10x/pretrained-models-with-keras/. It's got a working code example that you can look at as well.